# Fama: Efficient Capital Markets: A Review of Theory and Empirical Work - are martingales incorrect?

Tags: martingale, random-walk, market-efficiency

In his paper, Eugene Fama gives the definition of a "fair game" as given below. I disagree. AFAIK, a martingale has the following property: $E[X_{t+\tau} | X_t] = X_t$. What am I missing?

[image]

Footnote 9 says:

[image]
[image]

And again, in a previous statement:

[image]

Comment: What does Footnote 9 say?

Comment: @noob2 Nothing that would justify the zero in my opinion. I've updated.

Comment: What does it mean for martingales to be "incorrect"?

Answer (score 6):

The way I understand it is:

In equation 2 $x_{j, t + 1}$ is defined as the change in of $p_j$ over the period $t$ to $t + 1$. The formula says that the expectation of the change is zero which is the same as saying that the expectation of the original variable at $t+1$ is equal to its current value.